# Why does this function work with :post but not :pre?

Tags: hydra

```
(defhydra windows (global-map "C-c w" :post flash-active-buffer)
  "window moving"
  ("o" other-window "other"))

(make-face 'flash-active-buffer-face)
(set-face-attribute 'flash-active-buffer-face nil
                    :background "red"
                    :foreground "black")
(defun flash-active-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (run-at-time "250 millisec" nil
               (lambda (remap-cookie)
                 (face-remap-remove-relative remap-cookie))
               (face-remap-add-relative 'default 'flash-active-buffer-face)))
```

The above works as you'd expect: when the hydra exits, the final window flashes.  What I'd like is to flash the window as the focus moves about the frame.  However, instead of flashing the window, it will leave all *other* windows with the flash-color (in this case, completely red).

How can I get each window to flash as expected when using `:pre`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight after each switch, even when the hydra hasn't exited yet, you can use this:

```cl
(defhydra windows (global-map "C-c w"
                   :after-exit flash-active-buffer)
  "window moving"
  ("o" other-window "other"))
```

Another approach, which I think is actually better, since it's more straight forward:

```cl
(defhydra windows (global-map "C-c w")
  "window moving"
  ("o"
   (progn
     (other-window 1)
     (flash-active-buffer)) "other"))
```

A lot of similar info is summarized on the `internals` wiki page, [:after-exit](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/wiki/internals#after-exit) is there as well.

Comment: Nice! I guess I just misunderstood the docs :) Note: in order for this application of hydra to work well, you should shorten the flash. I have it set now for 50ms

Comment: I'd recommend to rewrite `flash-active-buffer` with overlays, since you can specify the window in which the overlay is visible.  Your current approach works badly if there are many windows with the same buffer.

Comment: It does indeed work badly -- but it's honestly a function I stole from someone else. Emacs' display architecture is not something I've invested time in understanding yet.

Comment: See `avy--make-backgrounds` - you can use it almost without change.